# How to modify SharePoint Online home page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, web-part

I want to modify SharePoint Online home page. I am trying to add the html, css and js in snnipt webpart but its not get work. I want to add the the Text, images and sliders section on the home page. I want to this using available webpart in SharePoint online.
Can anyone please help out me in this?

Comment: Are you using modern experience or classic experience? Which webpart are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Code snippet** web part on modern pages, it cannot be used to render code snippets but only “*display code as text on your page for others to use or learn from*”, quoted from the [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-code-snippet-web-part-d16d5aac-3e43-4d4d-aef3-d0ddbca64c05).

If you want to render custom code on the home page, take a look at the page and web part model **SharePoint Framework ([SPFx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview))**. Build [client-side web part](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/overview-client-side-web-parts) and perform responding actions.

Please note that customization on modern pages is restricted. See the reference here for supported customizations: [Customizing "modern" site pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages#supported-customizations-for-modern-pages).